# Checking CPU performance using check_nrpe—strange behaviour

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I'm having this strange problem: Using `check_nrpe`, it doesn't return correct result for `check_cpu_perf`. It works fine for other NRPE plug-ins though. e.g.

***On the Nagios Server:***

```
[root@ftppm01 nagios]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H talend-admin-app-01.local  -c check_users -a '5 10'
USERS OK - 1 users currently logged in |users=1;5;10;0

[root@ftppm01 nagios]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H talend-admin-app-01.local  -c check_load -a '15,10,5 30,25,20'
OK - load average: 0.00, 0.05, 0.08|load1=0.000;15.000;30.000;0; load5=0.050;10.000;25.000;0; load15=0.080;5.000;20.000;0; 

[root@ftppm01 nagios]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H talend-admin-app-01.local  -c check_cpu_perf -a '20 10'
OK: CPU Idle = % | CpuUser=; CpuNice=; CpuSystem=; CpuIowait=; CpuSteal=; CpuIdle=:20:10
```

On the client, `check_cpu_perf` works just fine by itself:

```
[root@ftaps01 plugins]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_cpu_perf/check_cpu_perf 20 10
OK: CPU Idle = 98.38% | CpuUser=0.34; CpuNice=0.00; CpuSystem=0.34; CpuIowait=0.94; CpuSteal=0.00; CpuIdle=98.38:20:10
```

But again, the very same result using `check_nrpe`:

```
[root@ftaps01-lvpr-uk-local plugins]# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_cpu_perf -a '20 10'
OK: CPU Idle = % | CpuUser=; CpuNice=; CpuSystem=; CpuIowait=; CpuSteal=; CpuIdle=:20:10
```

any idea what am I doing wrong? Or how to debug this issue? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what script you use, I found something similar here: 
http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/CPU-Usage-and-Load/Check-CPU-Performance/details

The above script uses sar, lparstat and lslpp. The nagios-nrpe module runs as nagios user and it is possible that sar ,lparstat or lslpp cannot be executed as non root users.

if you are not using the above script let us know what other script are you using.

Goodluck.

Comment: I think you are right. Looks like that's the scrip (it was already installed on the system) I'm using. That gives me something to look back in again.